# Can't reassign value to text field the second time

Tags: actionscript-3, uitextfield

The code below when it 1st load, i assign a pageName for selectedIDtext for it. And when the second time it loads I wanted to remove the data init and update with a new pageName. But no matter what I did i can't change and assign the 1st value that was loaded in the textfield.

```
selectedIDmc = new MovieClip();
selectedIDtext = new TextField();

selectedIDtext.defaultTextFormat = selectedIDformat;
selectedIDtext.wordWrap = true;

selectedIDtext.name = "selectedName";
selectedIDtext.opaqueBackground = 0x445566;
selectedIDtext.width = stage.stageWidth / 3;
selectedIDtext.height = 15;

function listClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (event.target.parent != listArray[listArray.length - 1]) {
        for (var i:Number = clickedIndex + 1; i < listArray.length; i++) {
            **selectedIDtext.text = ""**
        }

        pageName = event.target.getChildByName("listText").text;
        selectedIDtext.text = pageName;
    }
}
```

Comment: first load or first click? cause your event states that it is a MouseEvent?

Comment: 1st click, but the problem is it can't assign a value to it, and only able to trace it afer  selectedIDtext.text=pageName;

Comment: is selectedUDtext dynamic? or you just have one (1) selectedIDtext. cause your loop doesn't use your listArray.. its useless to loop

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
pageName=event.target.getChildByName("listText").text;
selectedIDtext.text=pageName;
```

try this

```
selectedIDtext.text=TextField(event.target).text;
```